# Save notebook widget state AND allow widget interaction after reloading notebook

Tags: jupyter-notebook, widget, plotly, jupyter

I am using interactive widgets to create plotly traces from dropdown menus. After creating a few traces and using *Save Notebook Widget State* and saving the notebook, I am able to reopen the notebook and still have my previous traces reload. However, the interactive widgets are no longer active and I am not able to add more traces after reloading the notebook. An icon also shows up next to the dropdowns and I don't know what it means.

I don't want to have to rebuild the plots from scratch every time. I also often need to save the plots and come back at various times to add more plots (traces).

How can I reactivate the interactive widgets (dropdowns) without losing my previously created traces?

[Saved widget state output example after reloading notebook](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fpyvv.png)

Comment: Did you manage to solve this ?

Comment: Not yet unfortunately